# Bazel: Run a command without an output

Tags: qemu, bazel

I am using bazel for building bare metal programs. I would like to run the unit tests generated by bazel on qemu.

`qemu-system-* -some_args -kernel bazel-bin/whatever/generated.elf`

I've tried to run those by creating my own rule in a '.bzl'-file, but it seems that outputs are mandatory on all the rule actions. Note, that I need to invoke different qemu commands with different arguments depending on the target architecture. I would like to pass those to the rule.

Is there a way to invoke a shell command without any outputs?

If needed, this is what I have so far (yet I'm not sure which parts are correct as bazel stops in the analysis phase):

```
# run_tests.bzl
===============
def _impl(ctx):
  qemu = ctx.attr.qemu
  machine = ctx.attr.machine
  cpu = ctx.attr.cpu
  target = ctx.attr.target
  # The command may only access files declared in inputs.
  ctx.actions.run_shell(
      arguments = [qemu, machine, cpu, target],
      command="$1 -M $2 -cpu $3 -nographic -monitor null -serial null -semihosting -kernel $4")

run_tests = rule(
    implementation=_impl,
    attrs = {"qemu" : attr.string(),
             "machine" : attr.string(),
             "cpu" : attr.string(),
             "target" : attr.string(),},
    executable = True
)
```

And my BUILD-File:

```
# BUILD
=======
load("//make:run_tests.bzl", "run_tests")

run_tests(
    name = "portos",
    qemu = "qemu-system-arm",
    machine = "realview-pbx-a9",
    cpu = "cortex-a9",
    target = ":test_portos.elf"
)

cc_binary(
    name = "test_portos.elf",
    srcs = glob(["*.cc"]),
    deps = ["//src:portos", 
            "@unity//:unity"],
    copts = ["-Isrc", 
             "-Iexternal/unity/src",
             "-Iexternal/unity/extras/fixture/src"] 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skylark has support for writing test rules. Basically instead of setting `executable = True`, you would set `test = True`, and then your rule would create an executable that is the test, then you set `ctx.outputs.executable` to that executable. Then you can use the `bazel test` command with your rule.

See:

docs: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/rules.html#test-rules

example: https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/master/rules/test_rule

rule.test: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#rule.test

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there: yes, you need outputs, otherwise bazel has nothing to do. For the rule output, you probably want the test logs or tests results.